# How to enable toolbars in a rendered aui dialog

Tags: dialog, alloy-ui

I am rendering the Aui dialog by setting toolbars : false in the configuration to disable close button(X) at corner of Aui dialog.

How to enable toolbars in a rendered aui dialog. i.e I want show (X)close icon after checking certain condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think simply hiding and showing the toolbar will do what you want. You can hide and show the toolbar of a modal like so:

```
modal.getToolbar(Y.WidgetStdMod.HEADER).hide();
modal.getToolbar(Y.WidgetStdMod.HEADER).show();
```

In order to satisfy your use case, you should hide the toolbar, show the modal, then when your condition is met, show the toolbar:

```
modal.getToolbar(Y.WidgetStdMod.HEADER).hide();
modal.show();

// Once your condition is met:
modal.getToolbar(Y.WidgetStdMod.HEADER).show();
```

If you need more information, check out the [`Toolbar` API Docs](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.Toolbar.html).

You can also select other toolbars besides the `HEADER` toolbar when using [`Modal.getToolbar()`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.Modal.html#method_getToolbar). Check out [the list of the other toolbar sections](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/WidgetStdMod.html) for more details.

Here's a runnable example:

```js
YUI().use('aui-modal', function(Y) {
  var modal = new Y.Modal({
    bodyContent: 'Modal body',
    headerContent: '<h3>Modal header</h3>',
    modal: false,
    render: '#modal',
    width: 450,
    visible: false
  }).render();

  modal.getToolbar(Y.WidgetStdMod.HEADER).hide();
  modal.show();

  Y.one('#button').on('click', function(event) {

    modal.getToolbar(Y.WidgetStdMod.HEADER).enable();
    modal.getToolbar(Y.WidgetStdMod.HEADER).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<div class="yui3-skin-sam">
  <button id="button">Show Toolbar</button>
  <div id="modal"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Hiding the toolbar does not disable it, so if you need to ensure that the user cannot access the toolbar, you will need to call [`Toolbar.disable()`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.Toolbar.html#method_disable) **and** you will need to disable all the inputs and buttons within the toolbar programmatically.